# Socket.io configuration error

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I use socket.io v.1.0.3.

and try to configure for production.

```
  var io = require('socket.io')(server);

            io.configure('production', function()
            {
                log(" set config for production");
                io.enable('browser client minification'); // send minified client
                io.enable('browser client etag'); // apply etag caching logic based on version number
                io.enable('browser client gzip'); // gzip the file
                io.set('log level', 1); // reduce logging
                io.set('transports', [ // enable all transports (optional if you want flashsocket)
                    'websocket', 'flashsocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling'
                ]);
            });
```

An error saying socket.io instance does not have `configure`

```
       io.configure('production', function()
               ^
TypeError: Object #<Server> has no method 'configure'
```

How?

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/1542

Comment: Thanks. So current version does not support this, right?

Comment: Yup. current version does not support io.configure

Answer (score 1):

I came accross this issue while trying to run my app on heroku as heroku doesn't let you use websockets atm. Setting the transport protocol in the on event worked for me.

```
io.on('connection', function () {
  io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]);
  io.set("polling duration", 10);
});
```